# Unable to Scroll 2 Grids simultaneously in ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web application using visual studio 2008 (ASP.Net 3.5 with C#). I have added two GridViews of System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView type. Now I want that when I scroll the GridView1 horizontally, the GridView2 also scrolls along with it. I have tried many solutions but whenever I tried to use the solution code, error occurred that 'does not contain a definition for Scroll/HorizontalScrollBar etc'. Even there is no GridView event for scrolling through which I can solve my problem.

If anybody has the solution then please let me know. I will be very pleased because I am trying to solve this problem from last 2 days.

Comment: This is outside of the realm of ASP.Net and C#. It must be done with JavaScript. How far have you got? Do you have your grids displaying side by side? Are you able to scroll them individually?

Comment: On a single web page I have two distinct Grids and I want to scroll one of them automatically as the user scrolls the other one. you are saying that this is not possible in pure C#, but I saw some solutions in which people are using C# commands. But those commands are not working in my application.

Comment: If there is a solution in Source code of the page then I also want to know about it.

Comment: put your gridviewS in an iframe, and put a horizontal scrollbar to the iframe. when u scroll to a side, you scroll both of the gridview. if you dont like the look of the default scrollbar, change the style of the scroll bar with css

Answer (score 0):

You can put your grids in two divs named `left` and `right` styling them with `overflow:scroll;`.

```html
<div id="left">
    ...grid1 here
</div>

<div id="right">
    ...grid2 here
</div>
```

Then you can use the following jQuery script to synchronize scrolling events:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#right').on('scroll', function () {
        $('#left').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    });
});
```